# Integrator circuit time calculation

Tags: integrated-circuit, adc

Suppose i'm charging the capacitor of an integrator until it reaches 5V, again after reaching 5V, Suppose I've designed a circuit so that, it starts discharging the capacitor of an integrator circuit until same negative polarity voltage. Will the time of charging and discharging remain same or different? Why? I have this question tickling on my mind while grasping concept on Dual Ramp ADC.

Comment: *I've designed a circuit* So why not show it here? Also **think** about what determines a capacitor's charge/discharge time. If the current is the same, is charging different from discharging?

Comment: Sorry i'm just supposing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a circuit similar to this: -

[image]

The schmitt trigger detects the triangle wave voltage reaching a specific positive limit and, because of this, its output reverses from negative to positive. This drives the integrator to produce a negative ramp and, when the lower threshold of the triangle is reached, the process starts over again.

Providing the output voltage of the schmitt trigger is equally positive and negative in magnitude, the integrator will maintain the ramp rate at a constant negative or positive level.

Answer (score 1):

The rate of voltage change of a capacitor is proportional to the current.

For example, if it took 2 seconds for the capacitor to go from 0 V to 5 V with xx A applied, then it will take 2 seconds to go from 5 V to 0 V with -xx A applied.  If you keep going, it will take another 2 seconds to reach -5 V.

Go back to the basic equation of what a capacitor does.